# Два фона по бокам, во всю ширину родительского блока (HTML CSS верстка)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сразу покажу скриншот того, что нужно сделать
http://joxi.ru/82QXlnCwwKvQmd
Опишу вкратце задачу, но думаю со скрина понятно, что нужно сделать.
В макете основная ширина контентного блока составляет 1140px

На скриншоте видим разделение блока на 2 не равные части, примерно 55% и 45%.

Измерил на макете контентную часть и так - левая часть (белая) составляет 680px и соответственно правая часть (серая) 480px;

Использую такую верстку:

```css
.main-content {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
}
.left-sidebar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: calc(100% - 1170px + 680px);
    background-color: green;
}
.right-sidebar {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 1170px + 460px);
    background-color: blue;
}
.left-container {
    max-width: 680px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
}
.right-container {
    max-width: 460px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="left-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-sidebar">
    <div class="right-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почти нормально попадает под контейнер выше, который имеет такие правила

```
max-width: 1140px и margin: 0 auto;
```

Но если открыть в разрешении `1920px` то наш блок смещается пикселей на `50`, относительно блока выше.

1368px - http://joxi.ru/nAy1gPFgg4xZAZ

1920px - http://joxi.ru/ZrJKoLFwwvq9mj

Есть ли какое-то универсальное решение, кроме как прибивать медиазапросами?

Comment: Без всего кода не понятно в чем разница между контейнерами. Добавьте хотябы стили от `container`. Что это `width: calc(100% - 1170px + 460px);` и какую ширину вы хотите получить?

Comment: Универсальное решение - это фреймворк (например bootstrap) а если вы хотите адаптивность, то придется прописывать медиазапросы.

Comment: @E_K В данном случае Калк лишний. Я сделал решение с помощью градиента для этого товарища.

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц В его случае, то разрешение о котором идёт речь - никакие медиа запросы не нужны. См моё решение.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%, #f5f5f5 50%);
    margin: 0px;
}
.main-content {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.left-zone {
    width: 680px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.right-zone {
    width: 460px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="left-zone">
  </div>
  <div class="right-zone">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На всю страницу смотреть.

Comment: ваш вариант не адаптивен. Сделайте обычную сетку `bootstrap` с блоками `col-md-9` + `col` и посмотрите как это выглядит. Здесь нужно привязать часть фона к блоку(`sidebar`).

Comment: @E_K Это шутка? В этой задаче есть условие: НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ фреймворки. Не подключать js и тому подобное. Ваш бутстрап - конструктор, но он не решает всё и вся, особенно для людей с фантазией. Я могу сам своими руками написать всё то, что я хочу.

Comment: @E_K Если вы хотите, то напишите на бэдстрапе свой вариант, дополнительно. И покажите. В остальном - задача, написать всё в одном документе БЕЗ сторонних файлов!

Comment: @E_K Прошу прощения. Я ошибся темой. Помог одному человеку, где стояла задача о том, что написал выше. Но. Причем тут бутстрап? Задача в другом. Я её сделал. Остальное - пусть как хотят, так и строят.

Comment: Комментарии можно удалять, если написали не туда. Про бутсрап написал для примера. Как с вашим вариантом мне сделать фон на сайдбаре и пространстве за ним (как на первом скриншоте вопроса), если его ширина 300px?

Comment: @E_K использовать комбинацию/и с медиа запросами.

Comment: @E_K Я не совсем понял твой вопрос? Больше конкретики + скрин с планом того, что ты хочешь сделать. Если имеешь в виду конкретно адаптацию под разные экраны, то медиазапросы. В остальном я выполнил задачу так, чтобы не писать лишнего кода.

Comment: [Скрин](http://joxi.net/82QXlnCwwKvQmd) с задачей выложил автор (изменить цвет фона от начала блока `sidebar`), вот даже [код](https://codepen.io/AFI/pen/KERbOO) для вас сделал. Ваш вариант ответа не подходит для этого, так как он жестко зависит от конкретного размера окна и медиа запросы здесь не помогут.

Comment: @E_K чушь. причем тут slidebar? Он не нужен в моей конструкции. Моя версия без адаптации под маленькие экраны, но под те разрешения, конкретные что он спрашивал - подходят. А вы не думали, что при адаптации у автора меняется конструкция сайта? Или вам не понятно что я сделал, реализация? В чем проблема? На скрине автора указано расстояние одного цвета и другого. Он хотел реализовать это с помощью блоков. У меня иное решение. Без них. Задайте вопрос автору темы, правильно я его понял или нет. Думаю правильно. Так что не придирайся ко мне. То что недопонимаешь - это другое.

Comment: @E_K Код? Зачем он мне? У тебя конструкция сайта в твоём коде другая. Не такая как у этого человека. Хочешь чтобы я для твоего кода подобрал решение? Пиши тогда Альтернативную Тему, там и посмотрим. Если время будет. Я не могу часто зависать на этом сайте. У самого дела есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91162/discussion-between-e-k-and-vladimir-rodichev).

Comment: @E_K пиши в вк если что, в профиле указан.

Answer (score 0):

Я, обычно, делаю такое при использование одного трюка с `max-width` и `margin: 0 auto`, выглядит это вот так:

```css
body {margin: 0;}
img {max-width: 100%;}
p {display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

.content {
  background: gray;
}
.max-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="max-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac dui id neque fermentum blandit a vel sem. Nunc orci est, ultricies et elementum ut, pharetra a odio. Aenean tincidunt nisi eget leo scelerisque pretium et ut nunc. Morbi at lectus nec mauris auctor blandit. Duis molestie velit sed velit porttitor, et tempor turpis pellentesque. Cras imperdiet libero a vehicula efficitur. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus mi metus, dignissim sit amet tristique quis, viverra ut urna.</p>
    <img src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2017/08/07/12/1502137604118189937.jpg" style="margin: 20px 0">
    <p>Nullam cursus, magna sit amet fermentum ultrices, erat leo tincidunt arcu, eu porta ipsum eros eget magna. Pellentesque euismod non felis sit amet vehicula. Donec lacinia urna id nibh facilisis pellentesque. Quisque pharetra, purus sit amet vulputate lacinia, ipsum turpis gravida sapien, sit amet hendrerit turpis nisl a est. Cras molestie volutpat mi, in elementum massa rhoncus eu. Sed vel tempor mauris. Vestibulum commodo dignissim pulvinar.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нажмите "На всю страницу".

Comment: Красиво. Но, ему, насколько я понял, нужно другое. См мой ответ.